# Curry tips for Haskell programmers

Tags: code-golf, tips, functional-programming, haskell

[Curry is the Language of the Month](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24640/language-of-the-month-for-april-2022-curry) this month and some users are starting to get into it, so let's get some [tips](/questions/tagged/tips) together.

Haskell and Curry are similar in a lot of ways and a lot of tips for Haskell work well in Curry and vice versa. So I'd like in this question to gather tips for [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) in Curry, that would be useful to someone who has read up on our [Haskell tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/19255/56656) extensively.

This would cover cool things you can do in Curry that you can't do in Haskell, as well as tips for getting around the cool things you *can't* do in Curry that you might be used to from Haskell.

Please post only one tip per answer.

Comment: does Curry support function haskelling?

Answer (score 11):

## Use `++` in patterns

In Haskell we are used to handling lists with `:` as our pattern.  Curry<sup>1</sup> can do this but it can also use `++` in patterns.  This can be used to pattern match longer prefixes for strings, e.g. this Haskell pattern:

```haskell
f('a':'b':'c':x) = ...
```

works in Curry, but can be shorter as:

```
f("abc"++x)=...
```

However it can also match much more exotic things.

```
f(x++"abc"++y)=...
```

This pattern matches all strings that have `abc` as a substring somewhere.  This can't even be written as a pattern in Haskell and requires a guard at the minimum.

```
f(a++[b])=...
```

This pattern matches lists ending with the element `b`.  It's the sort of pattern that Haskell programmers can attest would certainly be useful for many things.

This can be combined with other tricks to get *even more powerful* patterns, for example:

```
f(a++a)=...
```

This matches strings which are made up two copies of the same string concatenated.

`++` patterns aren't just a way to write certain patterns more efficiently. They allow us to represent much more complex patterns on lists than were even possible before.

---

<sup>1: `++` can be used as a pattern in PAKCS, KiCS, and MCC Curry, but does not work in Sloth, so this tip is not applicable there.</sup>

Answer (score 4):

## Use `?` as or-patterns

In languages like [Mathematica](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Alternatives.html) or [Rust](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch18-03-pattern-syntax.html#multiple-patterns) or [Python 3.10](https://peps.python.org/pep-0636/#or-patterns), there are some kind of "or-patterns", usually written in the form `a|b`, that could match either `a` or `b`. Haskell doesn't have such thing. But in Curry, you can write `a?b`.

For example, instead of

```haskell
f a=someExpr a
f b=someExpr b
```

You can write:

```haskell
f c@(a?b)=someExpr c
```

Unlike other languages, `?` isn't a special symbol for patterns. It is just a built-in function that returns either of the two values. Using `a?b` in patterns is just another example of functional patterns, just like [`a++b` in Wheat Wizard's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/245962/9288).